# PHP SQL Query is not returning anything using bind_param (returning false)

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a register PHP function that registers a user like so

```
//Function to create a new user
public function register($firstName, $lastName, $email, $state, $city, $password, $zipCode, $isHMan, $skills, $experience)
{
    $password = md5($password);
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO handyman(firstName, lastName, email, state, city, password, zipCode, isHMan, skills, experience) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $firstName, $lastName, $email, $state, $city, $password, $zipCode, $isHMan, $skills, $experience);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    if ($result) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function works perfectly when called and everything is inserted into my handyman table (including the md5 hashed password).  My problem is with my login function.  This is the function:

```
public function login($email, $password) {
    $password1 = md5($password);
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `handyman` WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password1);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {
        echo "results acquired";
        return true;
    } else {
        echo "no results";
        return false;
    }
}
```

When I run this I get this warning:

> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given.

And the program outputs no results.
After doing a search here on stackoverflow, people were saying that this is caused by an error in the SQL query and the $result variable actually is returning a false boolean value.  I input the query directly into my database with an email and password from my database and it executed perfectly.  I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong.  My values and SQL query seem to be correct.  I am guessing it may have something to do with the bind_param function but I don't know what.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed procedural style mysqli functions with object oriented.

You'll need to adjust that code you have to this:

```
public function login($email, $password) {
    $password1 = md5($password);  // don't do this btw
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `handyman` WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $password1);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows != 0) {
        echo "results acquired";
        return true;
    } else {
        echo "no results";
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: In order to check `num_rows` you need to have called `store_result` first.

You also need to alter your register method too since its looking at a failure bool from execute:

```
public function register($firstName, $lastName, $email, $state, $city, $password, $zipCode, $isHMan, $skills, $experience)
{
    $password = md5($password); // ahem .. no
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO handyman(firstName, lastName, email, state, city, password, zipCode, isHMan, skills, experience) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssssssss", $firstName, $lastName, $email, $state, $city, $password, $zipCode, $isHMan, $skills, $experience);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->affected_rows) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: Using `affected_rows` also needs `store_result` to be called. Don't check on the bool result of `execute` since that is used for failures in sql.

---

**PASSWORDS:**

Please look into `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for your storage and login procedures. `md5` is insecure, and out dated. Its beyond the scope of this Q/A to provide the full working usage of those functions. Please do look into them though.